# Docker not relasing memory

Tags: java, docker

We are running spring boot application in Docker container and we found that once the utilized some memory it never released it until we restart the container.
Is there any way to release the memory without container restart? Or any solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version of Java are we speaking about?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your java application rereleases memory when it runs out of a Docker container. Generally it is OK for enterprise Java applications to consume a static big amounts of RAM.